# JS - Regex for number without leading zero, or just zero

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression for currency (no commas or $ signs or periods; just integers), but I am hitting a wall.

I need a the number (as a string) to match a pattern to validate.

The following are what I need:
1. the number can be a single zero
2. the number cannot have leading zeroes

Valid Input:
0
12345
1230

Invalid:
00
012345

What I have so far:

```js
var regex = '^(?!00)([1-9][0-9]*)$';

var testCases = ['0', '12345', '0123', '456', '12340', '00123'];

for (var i in testCases) {
  var result = (testCases[i]).match(new RegExp(regex));
  
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(testCases[i] + ': ' + !!result);
  div.append(textNode);
  document.querySelector('#results').appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<div id='results'></div>
```

The only thing missing (I feel) is passing for the only 0 case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
/^(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)$/
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of an alternation group:

  - `[1-9][0-9]*` - a digit from `1` to `9` and then any 0+ digits
  - `|` - or
  - `0` - a `0`
- `)` - end of the group
- `$` - end of the string.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/u3hxjz/1).

JS demo:

```js
var regex = /^(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)$/;
var testCases = ['0', '12345', '0123', '456'];
for (var i in testCases) {
  var result = regex.test(testCases[i]); 
  console.log(testCases[i] + ': ' + result);      
}
```

Comment: Can I ask, what's an alteration group?

Comment: @SoluableNonagon It is a [grouping construct](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) with [alternation operator(s)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) inside.

Comment: This works, but not with decimals. 10.15 returns false, should be true

Comment: @chitgoks Of course, the question is about integers only. Adding fractional part is easy with `/^(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)(?:\.\d+)?$/`